# Countable basis of topology

Tags: general-topology

I know that the family $$\tilde{I}=\bigg\{(a,b)\;|\;-\infty<a<b<+\infty\bigg\}$$ is a basis of a single topology on $\mathbb{R}$, that is $\mathcal{T}(\mathbb{R})$ and the family

$$\overline{I}:=\{(a,b)\;|\;-\infty<a<b<+\infty\}\cup\{[-\infty,b)\;|\;-\infty<b<+\infty\}\cup\{(a,+\infty]\;|\;-\infty<a<+\infty\}$$
is a basis of a single topology on $\mathbb{\overline{R}=\mathbb{R}\cup{\{\pm\infty\}}}$ that is $\mathcal{T}(\mathbb{\overline{R}})$.

### Question

How can I claim that these bases are countable?

If I consider the family $$\tilde{I_1}=\bigg\{(a,b)\;|\;a,b\in\mathbb{Q}\;,-\infty<a<b<+\infty\bigg\},$$

then $\tilde{I}\supseteq \tilde{I_1}$, does the vice versa also holds?

In the same way if I consider the family $$\overline{I_1}:=\{(a,b)\;|\;a,b\in\mathbb{Q}\;,-\infty<a<b<+\infty\}\cup\{[-\infty,b)\;|\;-\infty<b<+\infty\}\cup\{(a,+\infty]\;|\;-\infty<a<+\infty\}$$ then,
$\overline{I}\supseteq \overline{I_1}$, does the vice versa also holds?

Thanks!

Comment: Your first two basis are not countable. You don't want $\tilde I=\tilde I_1$, you want that every interval in $\tilde I$ is included in an interval in $\tilde I_1$, and vice versa.

Comment: @NicolasFRANCOISI read on my book that $\mathcal{T}(\mathbb{R})$ and $\mathcal{T}(\mathbb{\overline{R}})$ are a a countable basis, why?

Comment: If $a$ and $b$ in your initial definitions can take any value in $\mathbb R$, then your sets are uncountable. That doesn't mean that the topology of $\mathbb R$ is uncountable, as you show by restricting yourself to bounds in $\mathbb Q$. The *basis* are uncountable, not the topology.

Comment: The correct statement is that *there exists* a countable basis for the standard topology on $\mathbb R$. That topology has many different bases, some of which are countable, and some of which are uncountable.

Comment: Ok. $\tilde{I}$ and $\overline{I}$ are uncountable basis, however if $a,b\in\mathbb{Q}$ the basis become countable. who guarantees me that the new bases with extremes in $\mathbb{Q}$ are bases of the same topology?

Comment: @JackJ. Because we can approximate all reals by rationals.